# How do I fix initramfs not finding root?

Tags: boot, grub2, 19.10, initramfs

I recently had a bad installed of Ubuntu 19.10 (and consecutive clean installs yield the same effect). I can boot to GRUB with no issue, but from there I only get a purple screen when trying to boot Ubuntu itself.

I tried several solutions found elsewhere, including trying to fix it through a Live USB, but to no avail.

The furthest I've yet gotten is specifying root, Linux, & initrd are located & telling it to boot.

But for some reason, initramfs tells me "No root device specified. Boot arguments must include a root=parameter."

I already told it what root was, what gives?

(Still a bit of a Linux n00b so bear with me, please)

Comment: when you boot up the computer you need to recreate initramfs: `update-initramfs -u -k all`

Comment: And where should I input this command? From GRUB?

Comment: No, from desktop session. You need to run two commands indeed. First `update-grub` then  `update-initramfs -u -k all`

Comment: So from Live USB? Because as I said, I can't even get to the desktop on the native install. But if that's what you mean, I'll give it a shot

Comment: I thought you could boot up and log in desktop session after providing kernel parameters. Take a look at this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot  If you fail then you have no choice but a liveusb. Do you have more than one partition  in your hard drive? Ubuntu 19.10 is not recommended, it has short term support. You need to use `18.04 , 19.04 or 20.04` versions.

Comment: If you have created a new partition prior boot failure, it may be the cause of the error. Be wary of data loss. Any mistake can lead to irrecoverable data loss.

Answer (score 5):

I followed [this specific guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/repair-linux-boot-with-grub-rescue/) and the thing that fixed it for me was following these instructions:

1. Find out which of your partitions contains your system. You can do this by typing `ls` to see all of your drives, and then `ls (hdX,gptX)` to see the contents of one of the partitions.
2. Once you've determined the correct partition (mine was `(hd3,gpt3)`) the next thing is you need to make sure that your prefix is set correctly. You can do this by typing in `set` to display all of the set variables. The tutorial shows an example where the prefix was set incorrectly.
3. If your partition was not set correctly, set the correct partition with `set prefix=(hd3,gpt3)/boot/grub`. Use your partition details.
4. Afterwards, set root value with `set root=(hd3,gpt3)`. Use your partition values.
5. `insmod normal` - Not sure what this does, but his tutorial says it loads a module.
6. The next part is to do `linux /boot/vmlinuz-XXXXXXXXX root=/dev/sdd3 ro` depending on whatever is on your machine.

⚠️ **The value that you should set to root varies, depending on which partition on your hard drive you installed your operating system on.**

In my case, I cut up my hard drive into 5 parts, and I used parts 3, 4, and 5 for my Ubuntu machine. Part 3 had the operating system, Part 4 had my swap files, and Part 5 had my hard drive data. (If you were in the desktop session already, you can check this using `lsblk` to see how the files were partitioned and what sizes they were assigned).

I used `sdd3` because the partition that held my OS is on the third partition of my drive `sdd`. This appears to be the missing part which caused me to get brought to initramfs with root not being specified.

7. Then do `initrd /boot/initrd-XXXXXXX`.
8. Finally, `boot`.

If there are other unix/linux/ubuntu specialists there who could give more clarity on what I may not have explained clearly, please feel free to edit this message.

Comment: The root value can be found by typing the following command: „cat /etc/fstab”